# restricting access on PAAS

Tags: paas

I have a lab setup in office where people work in a development environment that is hosted on a Cloud PAAS (like openshift or cloudbees).

The developers connect to the cloud git repository using SSH connection. They can easily take the SSH key to home and download the code at their home. I would like to restrict that activity.

Is their a software utility available that I can use to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want something like GitHub but self hosted? You can probably use one of the clones like [Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) to do so. Otherwise it's difficult to restrict user access to single user PaaSs.